# Got this error when tried a code using dagger hilt, Error:[Hilt] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit, build.gradle, dagger-hilt

I tried a code to make a currency converter in native Android using an API. I have used Retrofit, Dagger-Hilt and the MVVM architectural design pattern. After doing all the coding ,this is the error I got. The API fetches live currency exchange rates,which were converted from json to kotlin and used.

**Gradle file**
This is my gradle file with all the dependencies added.

```
plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.currency"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    //dagger - hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"

    //Activity KTX for viewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.1"

    //Architectural components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"

    //Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0"

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.1'

    //Coroutines Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0"
 }
```

Comment: the gradle file you posted does not seem to have any issues. the underlying issue must be something  with your code. can i check with you if your app has all the hilt entry points?

Comment: Plz check https://github.com/thefirelordx/CurrencyX

Comment: https://github.com/thefirelordx/CurrencyX/pull/1 here you go

Comment: thank you sir, the error is resolved.

Comment: sir i want to add graph of two currencies compared in the app(similar like XE currency converter app , what would be the approach? if you could please guide on it.

Comment: you need to look into graph libraries that are available for android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like i mentioned in the comments and my github PR. The solution is to use the same version of hilt-android, compiler

Answer (score 1):

I used hilt version 2.33-beta and same version of hilt-android,compiler,but I have encountered the same problem.Then I change the hilt version to 2.3.5 refering to Google codelab,everything is worked because I find that version is incompatible the kotlin version 1.5 or higher.